# Why is my loaded table in postgresql not ordered as it was in Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I've created a list of dictionaries from some API beer website and want to load all data into postgresql table. For this purpose I created a table("whole_table") with all columns and by use my own function (`filling_out_whole_table()`)inserted all data into this table. Like this:

```
with psycopg2.connect(host='127.0.0.1', database='beer', user='postgres') as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("""
                            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS whole_table;
                            CREATE TABLE whole_table
                            (
                                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                name TEXT,
                                tagline TEXT,
                                first_brewed TEXT,
                                description TEXT,
                                image_url TEXT,
                                abv DECIMAL,
                                ibu DECIMAL,
                                target_fg DECIMAL,
                                target_og DECIMAL,
                                ebc DECIMAL,
                                srm DECIMAL,
                                ph DECIMAL,
                                attenuation_level DECIMAL,
                                brewers_tips TEXT,
                                contributed_by TEXT
                            );
                      """)
        filling_out_whole_table(table = whole_table, cursor = cursor)
```

And this is function `filling_out_whole_table()`:

```
def filling_out_whole_table(table, cursor) -> None:
    my_list_of_dictonaries = [values for key, values in table.to_dict('index').items()]

    psycopg2.extras.execute_values\
    (
                                    cursor,
                                    """ INSERT INTO whole_table VALUES %s;""",

                                    ((
                                        beer['id'],
                                        beer['name'],
                                        beer['tagline'],
                                        beer['first_brewed'],
                                        beer['description'],
                                        beer['image_url'],
                                        beer['abv'],
                                        beer['ibu'],
                                        beer['target_fg'],
                                        beer['target_og'],
                                        beer['ebc'],
                                        beer['srm'],
                                        beer['ph'],
                                        beer['attenuation_level'],
                                        beer['brewers_tips'],
                                        beer['contributed_by'],
                                    )for beer in my_list_of_dictonaries),

                                    page_size= 1000
    )
```

After all was loaded I checked the order of my columns in my database and saw that some `id` fields are not ordered i.e. are not in place where they were before inserting. So my question is: Is it normal? Or maybe I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most SQL databases (including PostgreSQL) the order of the rows returned by a SELECT query is not guaranteed, unless you use an `ORDERED BY` clause.

So, what you observe is perfectly normal. But if your id fields respect the expected order, `SELECT * FROM whole_table ORDERED BY id` will return the rows in a consistent order.

Comment: @beginsql: Do not forget to accept the answer. That way future readers know that you no longer need help here.